# Allow Overlapping image with predefined size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Is it possible to allow to an image to overlap another div (bootstrap column), at a fixed size (155px in my case)

I use bootstrap column (col-9 and col-3)

Here is what i want to achieve (for the example, Orange and Grey boxes are images)
[image: overlaping image]

is there any other manner to achieve that ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by giving `col-9` margin right in negative value and make it above the other box with  `z-index` property as the following Code

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-9">
      col-9
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
      col-3
   </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.row > *{
    background: gray;
    height: 350px;
}

.col-9{
    background-color: orange;
    height: 195px;
    margin-top: 155px;
    margin-right: -40px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```